# Find an equation of the tangent line of the exponential function at the point (0,1)

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

So I differentiated the expression
$$ y=e^{2x}\cos(\pi x) $$ 
And I got
$$ y'=2e^{2x}\cos(\pi x)-\pi e^{2x}\sin(\pi x)$$
But when from the given point $(0,1)$ when I plug in zero I get 2

I looked the answer up in the back of my textbook (which I know I shouldn't do) and the answer is $y=2x+1$

Comment: $y'(0)=2$ gives you the slope of the line at $(0,1)$. You still need to find the equation of the line (given it's slope and a point lying on it).

Comment: I think this might be a case where you're not sure what you're actually looking for. You say you get $2$, which is indeed $y'(0)$. But you're not looking for a number, you're looking for a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a line $(y-y_0)=m(x-x_0)$, where $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point on the line and $m$ is the slope of the line.

You are correct in finding the derivative, since $m=y'(0)$. That is, the derivative at $x_0$ is the slope of the tangent line at $x_0$. So now you just have to use the point given to find the equation of the line,

$$ (y-1) = 2(x-0) \implies y=2x+1 $$